# ViewRootImpl mFallbackEventHandler memory Leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I found this memory leak using leak canary, I think is related to the InputHandler. It might be a bug on Android sdk

```
11-23 19:14:12.267 6871-8173/com.example D/LeakCanary: * com.example.ui.record.RecordActivity has leaked:
11-23 19:14:12.267 6871-8173/com.example D/LeakCanary: * GC ROOT android.view.ViewRootImpl[.this$0 (anonymous class implements android.view.InputHandler)
11-23 19:14:12.267 6871-8173/com.example D/LeakCanary: * references android.view.ViewRootImpl.mFallbackEventHandler
11-23 19:14:12.267 6871-8173/com.example D/LeakCanary: * references com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneFallbackEventHandler.mContext
11-23 19:14:12.267 6871-8173/com.example D/LeakCanary: * leaks com.example.ui.record.RecordActivity instance
11-23 19:14:12.267 6871-8173/com.example D/LeakCanary: * Reference Key: f8f44240-d6e0-475e-aaa4-bd6aa90de2bd]
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I want to know how to fix this memory leak, this is happening because RecordActivity references ViewRootImpl[.this$0, and the garbage collector doesn't clear the Activity memory because of that. And this happen becuase or android.view.ViewRootImpl.mFallbackEventHandler or com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneFallbackEventHandler.mContext have a reference to ViewRootImpl[.this$0